# How to go to another view when a button is pressed?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have Worklist view that contains a button. That button need to go to another view. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Sorry but although your question is clear, the scenario was not even given so it makes harder to people help you. Start from reading the documentation about routing and then update your question accordingly with what you got so far - https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/3d18f20bd2294228acb6910d8e8a5fb5

Comment: You need to be more specific, as fabiopagoti said. Please provide some code that you are trying, errors that you are getting and other informations that can be useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have your routes and targets set up in manifest.json you'll want to do somehing like this in your press event handler for the button.

```
this.getRouter().getTargets().display([TARGET NAME FROM MANIFEST]);
```

OR

```
this.getRouter().navTo("NAME OF ROUTE FROM MANIFEST");
```

Again like others have said this is highly dependent on use case, this is a general idea of what your solution may look like.